# How do I find the "full symmetric difference" of several files in bash?

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have five files that each list full file paths like so:

```
File one
    /full/file/path/one.xlsx
    /full/file/path/two.txt
    /full/file/path/three.pdf
    ....
File two
    /a/b/c/d/r.txt
    /full/file/path/two.txt
    ....
File three
    /obe/two/three/graph.m
    /full/file/path/two.txt
    ....
File four
    .....
File five
     .....
```

All five may contain the same exact full file paths. However, I want to filter out paths that are common to each file.  In other words, I want the total intersection of all files removed.  Below is a visual aid describing what I want with a smaller example of three files (excuse my poor mouse drawing skills):

[image]

The page on the [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference#n-ary_symmetric_difference) did not describe exactly what I wanted, hence the visual aid and the quotes around the phrase full symmetric difference.

## Question

How do I filter lines of text in several files to get the situation I want above?

Comment: Are you asking about finding/removing the longest common path segment? Because that's different than symmetric difference

Comment: No, if there is a path that is in five files, then I want to remove it from all five.

Comment: Does it need to be in Bash/awk/sed, or are there are scripting languages besides awk you'd be willing to use?

Comment: I mean....if you want to provide all the ways in your answer go ahead.  But I'll be more inclined to the quickest way that requires the least amount of code, I can use csh, bash, perl, awk, sed, or anything else that is part of the standard UNIX environment.

Comment: Do the files need to exist on the filesystem, or are they just strings in those five files?

Comment: Whether the actual file paths referenced by the five files exist or not won't matter.  They can be treated as just strings.

Comment: Just create a list of all five files together, sort it, then from the left start chopping off directory names (i.e. chop at '/' characters) that are present on all items in the list; as soon as you can't chop off from one item, you're done. I think you can even omit the sorting step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that that each file is free of duplicates you could

- Concat all files (`cat file1 file2 ... file5`)
- Count how often each line appears (`sort | uniq -c`)
- And keep only lines which appeared less than five times (`sed -En 's/^ *[1-4] //p'`)

```
sort file1 ... file5 | uniq -c | sed -En 's/^ *[1-4] //p'
```

However, if some file may contain the same line multiple times than you would have to remove these duplicates first.

```
f() { sort -u "$1"; }
sort <(f file1) ... <(f file5) | uniq -c | sed -En 's/^ *[1-4] //p'
```

or (a bit slower but easier to edit)

```
for i in file1 ... file5; do sort -u "$i"; done |
sort | uniq -c | sed -En 's/^ *[1-4] //p'
```

If for some reason you want to keep duplicates from individual files and also want to retain the original order of lines, then you can invert the above command to only print lines which appeared in every file and remove these lines using `grep`:

```
f() { sort -u "$1"; }
grep -Fxvhf <(sort <(f file1) ... <(f file5) |
              uniq -c | sed -En 's/^ *5 //p') file1 ... file5
```

or (a bit slower but easier to edit)

```
files=(file1 ... file5)
grep -Fxvhf <(for i in "${files[@]}"; do sort -u "$i"; done |
              sort | uniq -c | sed -En 's/^ *5 //p') "${files[@]}"
```